# Can I hide disabled users in the User Manager?

Tags: user-management, active-directory-module

We have Sitecore pulling user information out of Active Directory, and since a chunk of these are marked as disabled (University setting, and a chunk of our students get accounts for the time they're here), it results in a lot of extra results when searching for some common names.

In the Sitecore User Manager, is it possible to hide disabled users?

Comment: Have you used the custom filter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I propose hiding users through the use of filtering in the membership provider.

Consider using the **customFilter** attribute used by the Active Directory membership and role providers. Examples shown below.

Active Directory supports the following filter for excluding disabled users:

`(!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))`

You can find more details [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) on filters supported by Microsoft Active Directory; no guarantees that the AD module will recognize them all.

---

The **customFilter** attribute is documented in the AD module docs but there are not too many examples on how to do this in production.

I was able to get the filtering of disabled users working today. Thanks for the idea.

Use these filters in your web.config. Users which require access to Sitecore are added to the **GRP-Sitecore-Users** group in Active Directory. To keep things simple, this *tracking* group limits who appears in **User Manager**; the remaining access is configure in Sitecore on an individual user basis.

**SitecoreADMembershipProvider Custom Filter:**

```
(&amp;(memberOf=CN=GRP-Sitecore-Users,OU=Groups,OU=Company,DC=chs,DC=company,DC=corp)(!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))
```

**SitecoreADRoleProvider Custom Filter:**

```
(&amp;(objectCategory=group)(memberOf=CN=GRP-Sitecore-Users,OU=Groups,OU=Company,DC=chs,DC=company,DC=corp)(!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))
```

**Complete Example:**

A complete example demonstrating settings with the Active Directory module can be found [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1965/how-do-you-best-manage-security-domains-using-sxa-with-the-active-directory-modu/2033#2033). The only part missing is the *disabled* filter.

Comment: Can you expand on how you would apply this filter?

Comment: Link to the documentation: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Active_Directory.aspx

Comment: Awesome, didn't know that one.

Comment: Here is more detail on what I setup. http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1965/how-do-you-best-manage-security-domains-using-sxa-with-the-active-directory-modu/2033#2033

Comment: This worked perfectly for our needs. It additionally made me realize that our Active Directory module was out of date for our version of Sitecore. Thanks!

Comment: Sweet. Glad to hear that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no way to do this without modifying some logic.

**One way to do it would be:**
The User Manager dialog requests a list of users from the `UserProvider` which can be configured with a `web.config` patch:

```xml
<userManager defaultProvider="default" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="default" type="Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserProvider, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
  </providers>
</userManager>
```

You can then create your own class that overrides from `UserProvider` and override the `GetAllUsers()` method to only return users that are not disabled.

Note that for not-administrators that can view the User Manager, Sitecore is calling another piece of logic (something like `DomainProvider`) to get the users, so you also might want to tap into that.

**Another way to filter the user manager list:**
https://sitecorecontextitem.wordpress.com/2014/03/14/sitecore-user-manager-filter-users-by-profile-type/