# How to create multiple Sitecore Security Domain

Tags: security

We want to create multiple Sitecore security domains for different groups and their users. Can you advice as how to achieve this?

Comment: As mentioned by Patrick, you can use Domain manager. This adds domains in /App_Config/Security/Domains.config file. Additionally, you can refer to https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/security_and_administration/users_roles_and_domains/create_and_edit_a_security_domain

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the Domain Manager within Sitecore to create new security domains. From the Sitecore Desktop:

```
Start > Security Tools > Domain Manager
```

[image]

From there, you can setup your Sitecore Roles specifing your new domains, then assign users to the Domain Role.

Answer (score 20):

Editing the domains through the `Domain Manager` tool will cause `\App_Config\Security\Domains.config` to be updated with the added details. If you are updating this tool then make sure you include this in your project or copy it across to the other environments.

Unfortunately, the domains node is not patchable with Sitecore config overrides since it sits outside the `<sitecore>` node. You can however use a different `domainManager` which will use config and allow your domains to be patched like any other Sitecore config section.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <domainManager defaultProvider="file">
            <patch:attribute name="defaultProvider">config</patch:attribute>
        </domainManager>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

You can then patch in whatever domains you want:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <domainManager>
            <domains>
                <domain id="MyCustomNewDomain1" type="Sitecore.Security.Domains.Domain, Sitecore.Kernel">
                    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
                    <ensureAnonymousUser>false</ensureAnonymousUser>
                </domain>
                <domain id="MyCustomNewDomain2" type="Sitecore.Security.Domains.Domain, Sitecore.Kernel">
                    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
                    <ensureAnonymousUser>false</ensureAnonymousUser>
                </domain>
            </domains>
        </domainManager>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

You can read more about this in [Configuring domains from patch files](http://kamsar.net/index.php/2016/08/Configuring-domains-from-patch-files/) post by Kam Figy.

Comment: so much helpful

Comment: You may also find this answer helpful. It covers how to implement a provider that supports both options http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1965/how-do-you-best-manage-security-domains-using-sxa-with-the-active-directory-modu